# Conda Environment with Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, conda

I am looking at shipping in conda environment with reference to the below blog URL for pyspark yarn mode:
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/58418/running-pyspark-with-conda-env.html

The spark-submit command is provided as:

```sh
PYSPARK_PYTHON=./NLTK/nltk_env/bin/python spark-submit \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./NLTK/nltk_env/bin/python \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.NLTK_DATA=./ \
--master yarn-cluster \
--archives nltk_env.zip#NLTK,tokenizers.zip#tokenizers,taggers.zip#taggers \
spark_nltk_sample.py
```

I'm just having the below thoughts:

1) Understand from the blog that for the `--archives` files e.g. `nltk_env.zip#NLTK`, resource localization happens and there is a symbolic link created: `ln -sf "/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/vagrant/filecache/71/nltk_env.zip" "NLTK"`. Hence, the **PYSPARK_PYTHON** in both the drivers and the workers can use the python environment within the zip file during the spark job by accessing `./NLTK/`. In this case, how do the workers actually access the zipped python (`PYSPARK_PYTHON=./NLTK/nltk_env/bin/python`) & its associated conda env without actually unzipping and activating the conda env?

2) for the environment variable **PYSPARK_PYTHON**, it shows in the documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) that this variable applies to both the drivers and the workers. If this variable is set, do you still need to set the configuration `--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./NLTK/nltk_env/bin/python`? Is the Application Master configuration separate from executors?